# Group By Bye Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am a non-IT person working in a small company (10 folks). One of my jobs is to gather data and report that to our team. With that said, I use `MySQL`. Over the years, I have built various queries to pull the data. I recently upgraded our server to version 8. In version 8, the 'group by' rules are more strictly enforced. I am trying my best to rewrite some of my queries that violate the rules. However, I am struggling and need help in understanding how I should rewrite my queries.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT
  Manager,
  calldate_final as 'Call Date',
  putdate_final as 'Put Date', 
  concat('<a target="_blank" href="fi_details_by_security.php?manager=',frm.fi_details.manager,'&date=',frm.fi_details.MaturityDate_Final,'">',
  frm.fi_details.MaturityDate_Final,'<a/>') AS 'Maturity Date', 
  PortfolioCode as 'Portfolio',
  concat('$',format(sum(parvalue),0)) as 'Total Par Value', 
  count(parvalue) as 'Number of Maturities'
FROM frm.fi_details
WHERE Manager = WhereManager AND YEAR(MaturityDate_Final) = year(now())
GROUP BY portfoliocode, MaturityDate_Final
ORDER BY maturitydate_final, portfoliocode;
```

The end result is a summation of the par value of different holdings due by portfolio by date.

I appreciate your help. I have searched on this topic and frankly, I am more lost now. Any help and future guidance is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The change actually was pushed out in 5.7 so it seems like you jumped a few versions with your update. You may have other varying behaviors. You'll need to look at release notes for each version between your previous and current.

Comment: We were on 5.7 but the install base was part of Bitnami. This time we are doing an install of each component separately. I am guessing then Bitnami disabled this group by enforcement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mix normal columns (like 'Manager' or 'concat('<a target..' in your query) with aggregate functions (like `sum()` and `count()` in your query) you need to use `GROUP BY`. Earlier MySQL versions allowed very liberal (frankly false) use of `GROUP BY`.

To determine what to put into the `GROUP BY` is very straightforward. Just list all normal columns from your `SELECT` and leave out the ones in aggregate functions.

So, your query would become:

```
SELECT
  Manager,
  calldate_final as 'Call Date',
  putdate_final as 'Put Date', 
  concat('<a target="_blank" href="fi_details_by_security.php?manager=',frm.fi_details.manager,'&date=',frm.fi_details.MaturityDate_Final,'">',
  frm.fi_details.MaturityDate_Final,'<a/>') AS 'Maturity Date', 
  PortfolioCode as 'Portfolio',
  concat('$',format(sum(parvalue),0)) as 'Total Par Value', 
  count(parvalue) as 'Number of Maturities'
FROM frm.fi_details
WHERE Manager = WhereManager AND YEAR(MaturityDate_Final) = year(now())
GROUP BY Manager, calldate_final, `Maturity Date`, PortfolioCode
ORDER BY maturitydate_final, portfoliocode;
```